# Excel VBA to activate Powerpoint window by name

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have a macro in Excel that transfers data from Excel to tables in a Powerpoint file.  The macro runs smoothly on my computer, but, when I had a colleague try on his, he gets a Run-time error '5'

The error gets thrown a this portion of code:

```
VBA.AppActivate (Dir(sFileName))
```

sFileName is defined right before this as a file in a shared folder on our network.

Is there a better method of switching between a specific Excel window & a specific Powerpoint window?

Or, does anyone know what might be causing the difference in the macro's ability to run on my laptop vs my coworkers?  We both have Windows10 & Office 2016.

Thanks,

Comment: The only other way to do this is using WinAPI or ShellWindows - all depends on how comfortable you are with using an API call in your code

Comment: See, if you have any hard-coded file path which may be missing in other computer.

Comment: Why are you switching between the two apps?  Are you using activeworkbook or activepresentation?   If so, try accessing the file directly.